# Looking for a high-perfomance MCU for my thesis. The idea is to programme a digital processor that emulates tube amps in the best way possible

Tags: microcontroller, audio, dsp

I've read papers that used the PSoC 5LP but the writers felt their hands tied by the limitations of the board. I wanted to step it up in the hardware department without busting a bank because the idea is for the project I'm making to be the most affordable possible.

Since I have limited time to write my thesis it would be very important for the MCU I'm using to have built-in ADCs and DACs (16-bit each, preferably) on top of good speed and processing power.

I've taken a look at the Teensy 3.6 but the resolution of the converters seem low and I'm having a hard time finding a good alternative that meets my demands. I wonder if you guys could help me.

Comment: I think you’ll find that the common solution is to use an external audio adc/dac. Reason being that to fabricate good analog with microcontrollers is challenging.

Comment: The terms "most affordable" and "high performance" tend to be mutually exclusive. Have you considered setting a budget and then demonstrating what can be done within that?

Comment: This question is getting close votes because any answer will only be applicable for a short time.  I suggest you use the parametric search tools available for the various microcontrollers (such as [PIC](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/parametric-search/chartno_980)) to find one which meets your needs.

Comment: You don't even mention what performance you need like sampling rate or bandwidth of the signals, and what kind of voltages would the ADC and DAC need to support. Define these first before even starting to look for suitable components.

Comment: Do you know what makes tube amps sound like tube amps? What characteristics are you attempting to emulate? A thesis needs quantifiable requirements so you know if you have succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

> I've read papers that used the PSoC 5LP but the writers felt their hands tied by the limitations of the board

You'll probably be fine with any "higher end" ARM MCU.
Audio processing is not trivial but it's not super high speed either.

I you want to use floating point math (fixed point math is probably sufficient but not as convenient), I would highly recommend using a microcontroller with an integrated floating point unit (FPU) e.g Cortex-M4 / Cortex-M7 based ARM controllers.

> Since I have limited time to write my thesis it would be very important for the MCU I'm using to have built-in ADCs and DACs (16-bit each, preferably)

IMHO, this is not a very good idea. The ADCs/DACs are the most important part of your system. You don't want to save money here.

Integrated ADCs/DACs will always make problems due to the nearby digital stuff. Furthermore your requirements of 16 bit resolution shrink down your choice of MCUs severly.

I would go with separate (audio) ADCs and DACs. Audio ADCs/DACs often have an digital I2S interface which the most microcontrollers have hardware interfaces for. So communicating with external analog converters is usually not that much of a hassle.

On top of that, external analog circuitry is much easier to handle with regards to noise, disturbances etc. Your design doesn't sound very complicated:
`Audio-> ADC -> MCU -> DAC -> Audio`. The board design will probably allow for the analog and digital circuit to be spaced apart quite a bit which will basically take care of most interference and make the board design much easier.

If you're doing the board layout yourself, I can highly recommend the info from Rick Hartley's talks: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vALt6Sd9vlY

---

My approach to the whole thing would be:

- Take a development board of a cortex-m4/m7 processor like STM32F4/STM32F7 series (other manufacturers have very similar families... So this is not an issue). Deveopment boards are currently still available. Acquiring chips can get harder due to the semiconductor shortage at the moment.
- Get decent audio ADC and DAC (24 bit @ 192kHz?) from e.g. TI / AD / ...
- Design analog board for ADC/DAC (or maybe get a dev board of these, too)
- Connect analog board to MCU Dev-Board and start programming.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply nonlinear processing (like the transfer function of a tube) to sampled data, then you need to oversample it first so you have enough points in the waveform. So you'll need enough processing power for oversampling and decimating.

Don't expect any good audio quality out of a microcontroller ADC. It is much easier to use a micro with an I2S port (input and output) and your choice of audio CODEC (ADC+DAC) chip. If you run it at a high sample rate, you'll save cpu cycles on oversampling.

For convenience, you can definitely make a prototype on a PC with a soundcard. This will allow you to develop the signal processing code quickly and efficiencly, and when the code does what you want, you will be able to estimate how much processing power you need in your DSP/micro and then choose one. If you don't estimate how much processing power you need, then you'll have to go overkill, with something like a Raspberry Pi or other smartphone-style SOC with I2S ports.

While a DSP would probably be an effective choice, ARM Cortex chips are also a good option, they have fast DSP instructions and I2S ports too.